# Why does Symfony create a separate vendor folder in my root?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

when I install Symfony [according to the guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#option-1-composer) (option 1 with composer) it creates the folder structure as expected (and mentioned in that guide):

```
path/to/webroot/
    Symfony/
        app/
        src/
        vendor/
        web/
```

But in the root folder it also creates an empty `vendor/` folder. In this vendor folder there is a subfolder named `composer/`.

```
path/to/webroot/
    Symfony/
    vendor/
        composer/
```

Both directories are empty (no hidden files). So two questions:

1. Is this a required folder or is it kind of a bug that these folders are installed? Or may this be a directory for composer-specific files?
2. Can I delete this folder without any danger?

Comment: Go to next step of the guide ! http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#updating-vendors

Comment: This loads all relevant vendor content into `root/Symfony/vendor/`, but I was asking about the `root/vendor/` folder (which is not in `Symfony/`)

Comment: root/vendor is for third party plugins which you're pulling in - anything that is in composer.json. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html

Comment: You can safely delete the empty webroot/vendor folder.  I'm guessing it might have taken you several tries to get the install syntax correct?  Somewhere along the line the folder was created by accident.  It should not be there.  As an experiment you could repeat the installation process in some other directory.  Or just delete it and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That empty folder is generated when you don't pass the target-directory parameter to composer:

```
php composer.phar create-project vendor/project target-directory [version]
```